# Compilation error in building math expression evaluator with Boost.Spirit

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to parse math expression into a tree and evaluate it later with specific variables (char). Here is my grammar:

```cpp
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>

struct Expression;
struct SubFunction;
using OperandVariant = boost::variant<double, char, boost::recursive_wrapper<SubFunction>, boost::recursive_wrapper<Expression>>;

struct SubFunction
{
    std::string name;
    std::vector<OperandVariant> arguments;
};

struct Operation
{
    std::string type;
    OperandVariant operand;
};

struct Expression
{
    OperandVariant operand;
    std::vector<Operation> operations;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        SubFunction,
        (std::string, name)
        (std::vector<OperandVariant>, arguments)
        )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        Operation,
        (std::string, type)
        (OperandVariant, operand)
        )

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
        Expression,
        (OperandVariant, operand)
        (std::vector<Operation>, operations)
        )

template <typename Iterator>
struct FunctionGrammar : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<Iterator, Expression(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
    FunctionGrammar() : FunctionGrammar::base_type(logic)
    {
        using boost::spirit::qi::string;
        using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::lexeme;
        using boost::spirit::qi::char_;
        using boost::spirit::qi::lit;
        using boost::spirit::qi::attr;

        logic = relation >> *(string("&&") >> relation
                              | string("^^") >> relation
                              | string("||") >> relation);
        relation = addition >> *(string("<=") >> addition
                                 | string(">=") >> addition
                                 | string("!=") >> addition
                                 | string("==") >> addition
                                 | char_('>') >> addition
                                 | char_('<') >> addition);
        addition = multiplication >> *(char_('+') >> multiplication
                                       | char_('-') >> multiplication);
        multiplication = value >> *(char_('*') >> value
                                    | char_('/') >> value);
        value = '(' >> logic >> ')'
                 | +(char_ - '(') >> '(' >> value % ',' >> ')'
                 | double_
                 | char_;
    }

    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Expression(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> logic;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Expression(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> relation;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Expression(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> addition;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, Expression(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> multiplication;
    boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, OperandVariant(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> value;
};
```

I did this based on [an example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/compiler_tutorial/) from the official documentation and it works. But I want to add the ability to use `+`, `-`, `*` etc. inside a `Subfunction` arguments (that splitted by `,`). If I replace this part

```cpp
+(char_ - '(') >> '(' >> value % ',' >> ')'
```

into this:

```cpp
+(char_ - '(') >> '(' >> logic % ',' >> ')'
```

the code will not compile. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+(char_ - '(') >> '(' >> value % ',' >> ')'` parser has `fusion::vector<std::string, std::vector<OperandVariant> >` attribute type, it can be converted to `SubFunction` and stored in `OperandVariant` (the attribute of `value` rule), while `+(char_ - '(') >> '(' >> logic % ',' >> ')'` parser has `fusion::vector<std::string, std::vector<Expression> >` attribute type and cannot be converted to any type that `OperandVariant` can hold.

That explanation could also be deciphered from this part of a Clang output:

```
/opt/wandbox/boost-1.72.0/clang-head/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/assign_to.hpp:153:20: error: no matching conversion for static_cast from 'const boost::fusion::vector<std::__1::vector<char, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::vector<Expression, std::__1::allocator<Expression> > >' to 'boost::variant<double, char, boost::recursive_wrapper<SubFunction>, boost::recursive_wrapper<Expression> >'
            attr = static_cast<Attribute>(val);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: How can I tell to grammar to expand this values into std::vector? I thought using `logic % ','` allows you to do this automatically.

Comment: I expanded my answer. Please reread it (and the compiler error). The problem is in your AST. The grammar and AST are tightly coupled, and if you changing one, most likely you need to change the other too.

Comment: Thank you, changed `arguments` type to `std::vector<Expression>`.